# Deploy docker image from Github registry to Digital Ocean droplet using Github Actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

My aim is to have continuous deployment of a nodejs-express application to my digital ocean droplet.

I have a dockerized nodejs application, I am building an image and pushing the image into github packages registry. Now I want deploy this image into digital ocean droplet using github actions.

How can  I do that?

My current github action file is the following:

```
name: Docker

on:
  push:
    # Publish `master` as Docker `latest` image.
    branches:
      - master

    # Publish `v1.2.3` tags as releases.
    tags:
      - v*

  # Run tests for any PRs.
  pull_request:

env:
  # TODO: Change variable to your image's name.
  IMAGE_NAME: image

jobs:
  # Run tests.
  # See also https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/automated-testing/
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          if [ -f docker-compose.test.yml ]; then
            docker-compose --file docker-compose.test.yml build
            docker-compose --file docker-compose.test.yml run sut
          else
            docker build . --file Dockerfile
          fi
  # Push image to GitHub Packages.
  # See also https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/
  push:
    # Ensure test job passes before pushing image.
    needs: test

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event_name == 'push'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build image
        run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag $IMAGE_NAME

      - name: Log into registry
        run: echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Push image
        run: |
          IMAGE_ID=docker.pkg.github.com/${{ github.repository }}/$IMAGE_NAME
          # Change all uppercase to lowercase
          IMAGE_ID=$(echo $IMAGE_ID | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
          # Strip git ref prefix from version
          VERSION=$(echo "${{ github.ref }}" | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
          # Strip "v" prefix from tag name
          [[ "${{ github.ref }}" == "refs/tags/"* ]] && VERSION=$(echo $VERSION | sed -e 's/^v//')
          # Use Docker `latest` tag convention
          [ "$VERSION" == "master" ] && VERSION=latest
          echo IMAGE_ID=$IMAGE_ID
          echo VERSION=$VERSION
          docker tag $IMAGE_NAME $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
          docker push $IMAGE_ID:$VERSION
```

For SCP should the following code be fine? Please correct me if I am not using the correct file name variable here

```
 copy: 
     # Ensure test job passes before pushing image.
     needs: push
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Copy file via scp
          uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
          env:
            HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
            USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
            PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
            KEY: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
          with:
            source: "$IMAGE_NAME"
            target: "/usr/images/"
``
```

Comment: [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-deploy-using-github-action) might help.

Comment: @ParthShah Thanks for the info. After doing ssh, what docker command should I run to pull image from github package registry?  How will I give github authentication if its a private repository?

Comment: You're basically copying files using SCP and then executing the remote command using `script` in two different actions.

Comment: @ParthShah Shouldnt I be pulling the image using docker pull docker.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY/IMAGE_NAME:TAG_NAME after ssh?  Instead of SCP.

Comment: @ParthShah For SCP please correct me if me I am using the wrong file name here.   copy: 
     # Ensure test job passes before pushing image.
     needs: push
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        - name: Copy file via scp
          uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
          env:
            HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
            USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
            PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
            KEY: ${{ secrets.SSHKEY }}
          with:
            source: "$IMAGE_NAME"
            target: "/usr/images/"